# TFS2015: Full File Path Stored in SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports, tfs-2015

I'm looking to see if the SQL Database behind TFS2015 (or any version of TFS, in this case 2015 or 2010) stores the full file path for a file. There is information that we include in the Project folder (namely the version number) and while I realize there are better ways to track this information, we have a lot of legacy data that only has the version stored within this path. I want to pull the data into Crystal Reports to strip off the information and then use it.

[image: Screenshot of the information I'm hoping to pull from database]

Comment: I don't have an on-premises version of TFS handy, but when I was spelunking in there to generate some reports, I found [this query](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/worst-query-i-ever-wrote.html) to be invaluable. Run that against your tfs_default database for whatever you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You want to get a list of folders in TFS Source Control, instead of querying in database, we recommend to achieve it programmatically. The blog below and the sample code associated with it will do what you want:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/02/26/tfs-api-part-16-mapping-source-control-using-versioncontrolserver.aspx

Also, check the code snippet in [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b162dfad-354a-4584-a9eb-f2b7ce6f9393/to-get-folder-list-under-team-project?forum=tfsversioncontrol), which should help you:

```
ICommonStructureService structureService = (ICommonStructureService)Tfscollection.GetService(typeof(ICommonStructureService));
            ProjectInfo[] projects = structureService.ListAllProjects();
            //combo_projects.ItemsSource = projects;
            ////Create VersionControlServer object from TFS 
            //sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
            RecursionType recursion = RecursionType.OneLevel;
            Item[] items = null;
            string path = "$/" + projects[0].Name;//"$/TescoPOC/FetchStoryfromTFS";
            ItemSet itemSet = versionControl.GetItems(path, recursion);
            items = itemSet.Items;
            //Dictionary<string, int> FolderListName = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            List<string> FolderListName = new List<string>();
            foreach (Item keyItem in items)
            {
                char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '/' };
                //Using split to isolated the Project Name and the File Name
                string[] ss = keyItem.ServerItem.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (keyItem != items[0])
                {
                    string filename = keyItem.ServerItem.Replace(path + "/", string.Empty);
                    if (filename != "BuildProcessTemplates")
                    {
                        FolderListName.Add(filename);
                        //if (FolderListName.ContainsKey(filename))
                        //    FolderListName[filename] = FolderListName[filename] + 1;
                        //else
                        //    FolderListName.Add(filename, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```